# Robocopy: ERROR 87 (0x00000057) Time-Stamping Destination Directory

Tags: sata, robocopy, usb-to-sata

I'm using robocopy to copy files from a CD drive to a SATA drive in USB-to-SATA enclosure. This is the command that I'm using:

```
FOR /F "tokens=6" %%a IN ('vol e:') DO SET var=%%a
md k:\%var%
robocopy e:\ k:\%var%\ /s /XO /R:1 /W:1
```

The files seem to be copying OK but I am getting alot of these errors:

```
ERROR 87 (0x00000057) Time-Stamping Destination Directory
...The parameter is incorrect.
```

Any idea what this means, and what might be causing it?

I'm running Windows 10 Pro 21H2

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying to FAT, then add the `/FFT` parameter to
assume FAT file times (2 second granularity).

You could also try using the `/COPY:DT` parameter.
By default, robocopy copies data, attributes and timestamp,
and this parameter will skip the attributes.

Try also with `/copy:dt /dcopy:t`.

If the file systems on the source and target are different,
for example NTFS and exFAT, it would be better to use xcopy
for copying.

Question: Do you have funny dates, like far in the past/future,
for some of your files or folders?
You will find the name of the file or folder listed in the
error message.

A workaround that worked for some people having this problem is
to copy the directory structure first using xcopy.

Example:

```
xcopy /t /e "FROM" "TO"
robocopy.exe "FROM" "TO" /mir /R:0
```

Comment: The source (the CD drive) is CDFS. The target drive is NTFS. I've just tried adding /copy:dt /dcopy:t but got the same errors. I'm using robocopy rather than xcopy because I'm getting quite a few CRC errors etc on the optical discs that I'm copying and I want them to be skipped over.

Comment: In case of errors, try [Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier](https://www.roadkil.net/program.php?ProgramID=29). It's old, but might still work. Or try [its alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/roadkils-unstoppable-copier/).